# AFNetworking POST method with nested NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

I am using AF-networking 2. I want to send the Nested `NSMutableDictionary` to server. This is the method I am using.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayRecordSet =[NSMutableArray array];
    for (id contact in _contactGroupArr) {

        ContactGroup *contactGroup=contact;

        NSMutableDictionary *dictGroupDetails=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:contactGroup.guid forKey:@"guid"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:contactGroup.name forKey:@"name"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:@"" forKey:@"description"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:contactGroup.status forKey:@"isDeleted"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictContactGroup=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dictContactGroup setObject:dictGroupDetails forKey:@"contact_group"];

        [arrayRecordSet addObject:dictContactGroup];

    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dictSyncData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dictSyncData setObject:arrayRecordSet forKey:@"recordset"];
    [dictSyncData setValue:@"2014-06-30 04:47:45" forKey:@"last_sync_date"];

    NSString *getPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:API_SYNC_CONATCTGROUP];

    [self POST:getPath parameters:dictSyncData
       success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

           NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
       }
       failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"%@",error);
       }];
```

But server expecting Json format is

```
Array
(
    [last_sync_date] => 2014-06-30 04:47:45
    [recordset] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [guid] => y37845y8y
                            [name] => Family
                            [description] => Family members
                            [isDeleted] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [guid] => gt45tergh4
                            [name] => Office
                            [description] => Office members
                            [isDeleted] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But my code is sending this wrong format

```
Array
(
    [last_sync_date] => 2014-06-30 04:47:45
    [recordset] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [description] => 
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [guid] => 8D9763F6-38EF-49C7-860D-62759D77A779
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [isDeleted] => 1
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => dfhdfhfd
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [description] => 
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [guid] => B9AC3F61-6F35-4447-87CE-6399E863C84A
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [isDeleted] => 1
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => eretert
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [description] => 
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [guid] => 8D651A62-ABDE-4062-96EF-0922768008FA
                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [isDeleted] => 1
                        )

                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [contact_group] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => gghfgh
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But I checked my `NSMutableDictionary`. It is correct. Because manually I create the `NSJson` string. It will give the correct format. I thing afnetworking create the wrong json format.

I give my full effort. But still I have the problem

**EDIT**

Server expecting json

```
{  

    "last_sync_date": "2014-06-30 04:47:45",

    "recordset": [

        {

            "contact_group": {

                "guid": "y37845y8y",

                "name": "Family",        

                "description": "Family members",              

                "isDeleted": 0        

            } 

        },

        {

            "contact_group": { 

                "guid": "gt45tergh4",        

                "name": "Office",        

                "description": "Office members",              

                "isDeleted": 0        

            } 

        } 

    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have to warp the `contact_group` dictionary within another dictionary. Try something like this.

```
int index = 0;

for (id contact in _contactGroupArr) {

        ContactGroup *contactGroup=contact;

        //level 1
        NSMutableDictionary *dictGroupDetails=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:contactGroup.guid forKey:@"guid"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:contactGroup.name forKey:@"name"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:@"" forKey:@"description"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:contactGroup.status forKey:@"isDeleted"];

        //level 2
        NSMutableDictionary *dictContactGroup=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dictContactGroup setObject:dictGroupDetails forKey:@"contact_group"];

        //level 3
        NSMutableDictionary *dictArry=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dictArry setObject:dictContactGroup forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index]];

        [arrayRecordSet addObject:dictArry];

        index ++;

    }
```

Here what I did at level 3 was wrap the `dictContactGroup` NSMutableDictionary within another NSMutableDictionary called `dictArry` to make the JSON object structuer as this.

```
    [0] => Array
    (
       [contact_group] => Array
         (
            [guid] => y37845y8y
            [name] => Family
            [description] => Family members
            [isDeleted] => 0
         )

    )
```

Comment: [_contactGroupArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing an extra layer in the part:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictContactGroup=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictContactGroup setObject:dictGroupDetails forKey:@"contact_group"];
```

I think you need to wrap your:

```
dictGroupDetails
```

into another array then set that array as the object of dictContactGroup, so something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictContactGroup=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 

NSArray *wrapperArray = @[dictGroupDetails];

[dictContactGroup setObject:wrapperArray forKey:@"contact_group"];
```

Can you see what I mean?

### Extra edit 1

Forgot to also mention, from your supposed expected output, it also appears that each element in arrRecordSet contains an array of contact group.

You'll likely also need to wrap your dictContactGroup itself within an outer wrapperArray:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictContactGroup=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 

NSArray *wrapperArray = @[dictGroupDetails];

[dictContactGroup setObject:wrapperArray forKey:@"contact_group"];

// notice the extra @[ ]  wrapped around "dictContactGroup"
[arrayRecordSet addObject:@[dictContactGroup]];
```

### Extra edit 2

I'm not sure whether the above "expected output" you provided above is accurate, you seem to have manually typed it out.

I've written a quick demo app to test the logic above:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSMutableArray *arrRecordSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *arrContactGroups = @[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5];

    for(int i = 0; i < arrContactGroups.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictGroupDetails=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:@"1234" forKey:@"guid"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:@"group name" forKey:@"name"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:@"group description" forKey:@"description"];
        [dictGroupDetails setObject:@"not deleted" forKey:@"isDeleted"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictContactGroup=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dictContactGroup setObject:@[dictGroupDetails] forKey:@"contact_group"];

        [arrRecordSet addObject:@[dictContactGroup]];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dictSyncData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dictSyncData setObject:arrRecordSet forKey:@"recordset"];
    [dictSyncData setValue:@"2014-06-30 04:47:45" forKey:@"last_sync_date"];

    NSLog(@"dictSyncData = \n\n%@", dictSyncData);

}
```

The output I got is:

```
{
    "last_sync_date" = "2014-06-30 04:47:45";
    recordset =     (
                (
                        {
                "contact_group" =                 (
                                        {
                        description = "group description";
                        guid = 1234;
                        isDeleted = "not deleted";
                        name = "group name";
                    }
                );
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                "contact_group" =                 (
                                        {
                        description = "group description";
                        guid = 1234;
                        isDeleted = "not deleted";
                        name = "group name";
                    }
                );
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                "contact_group" =                 (
                                        {
                        description = "group description";
                        guid = 1234;
                        isDeleted = "not deleted";
                        name = "group name";
                    }
                );
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                "contact_group" =                 (
                                        {
                        description = "group description";
                        guid = 1234;
                        isDeleted = "not deleted";
                        name = "group name";
                    }
                );
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                "contact_group" =                 (
                                        {
                        description = "group description";
                        guid = 1234;
                        isDeleted = "not deleted";
                        name = "group name";
                    }
                );
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                "contact_group" =                 (
                                        {
                        description = "group description";
                        guid = 1234;
                        isDeleted = "not deleted";
                        name = "group name";
                    }
                );
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Which matches your expected output, so I think there's something lost in translation here.

Can you provide us with the actual results of the console output from your app and not a manually typed out version that you did?

Comment: [last_sync_date] => 2014-06-30 04:47:45
    [recordset] => Array
        ([0] => Array
                ([contact_group] => Array
                        ( [0] => Array
                                ([description] =>   )
 )
) [1] => Array ([contact_group] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                    [guid] => 8D9763F6-38EF-49C7-860D-62759D77A779
                                )

                        )

                )

Comment: Say, not sure if this will help but are you sending your response as JSON to the server using [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]; or are you using the [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];  ?

Comment: I tried all the ways. But not working. Check the edited version. I attached server expected json format. I thing it will help you

Comment: Can you also edit your question with the real console log result of NSLog(@"dictSyncData = \n\n%@", dictSyncData); right before the line NSString *getPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:API_SYNC_CONATCTGROUP]; ?